# How to clear AmbiguousModuleResolutionError?

Tags: git, react-native, npm, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

everyone. I'm new to React Native, so bear with me. Working with VSCode.

I wanted to add a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible-tab-header) to try out to my project, but it was only accessible via yarn (I hadn't used it beforehand). So I installed it via chocolatey and everything was OK. However, after trying to run the project an error appeared -- "Ambiguous resolution: module  tries to require 'react-native', but there are several files providing this module."

So I tried clearing yarn, npm, node_modules, the vscode react native tools, uninstalling the app, re-cloning the source from git, removing the package manually, but nothing works.

One thing that *did* work is `npm start --clear-cache` when done via the terminal in vscode (found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15789#issuecomment-327115978)). However, this requires additional command to write and is tedious. How can I purge whatever cache there is left and continue debugging as I have before?

If you need more info, tell me.

Edit: It seems it is related to the folder the project resides in. I cloned the repo in a differently named folder and it works. I'll add this as an answer/workaround in a couple of days if nobody gives an actual resolution.

Comment: Just for clarity, packages that are available on yarn are also available on npm and vice versa, some people simply prefer one over the other and outline only that in their library readme.

Comment: Yeah, I gathered that. Neither of the cache cleans worked, just wanted to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved on since, but the solution in the question stands. Adding it so this question has an answer, at least.

> It seems it is related to the folder the project resides in. I cloned the repo in a differently named folder and it works.